# Filter rows of a CSV using an Array to show arrayItem : 1 in CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I have built the following function that, when a user presses a button, the string is appended to an array (and also, the button changes red). I have d3, and JQ(not yet used) in my scripts:

```
 // Create button click array

var clickedBusinesses = [];

function toggle(business) {
    clickedBusinesses[business] = !clickedBusinesses[business];
  };

function getClickedBusinesses() {
return Object.keys(clickedBusinesses).filter(key => clickedBusinesses[key]);
};


// Update array and change button colour to reflect selection
function toggleClickedBuz( bizStr , id ) {
    if(clickedBusinesses.includes(bizStr)){
       // removing duplicate element from that array, dependant on button pressed
       clickedBusinesses = clickedBusinesses.filter( cb => cb !== bizStr );
       document.getElementById( id ).style.backgroundColor='white';
    }else{
        // else push it to the array
       clickedBusinesses.push(bizStr)
       document.getElementById( id ).style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
    console.log(clickedBusinesses)
    var arrayLength = clickedBusinesses.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(clickedBusinesses[i]);
    // Do something
}
  }
```

I am trying to use this array to filter on columns in a CSV to only display the value '1.0'

```
    const data = d3.csv("./binary.csv").then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This is how each row looks (6k) in the console window:

```
{is_active: "1", "Bx": "1", "By": "1", "Bz": "0", count: "5,133,151"}
```

I'm struggling on creating the logic that iterates through the data and only returns values where a specific key (Bx, By, Bz - depending on the selection) has the specified value(1).

Thanks

Comment: not sure i understand the problem..   maybe your want to interate the array and filter all objects with matching prop values:  `matchingObjs = someArr.filter(o => o.id == 1)` , or if there is only one match expected use:  `matchedObj = someArr.find(o => o.id == 1)` where in my example id is the property im matching on

Comment: Hey mate. I don't really know how to build the function that can iterate through the array clickedBusinesses against the CSV to modify rows to display keys(as per the array) to only select my chosen value.

Comment: `matchedObsj = clickedBusinesses.filter(o => o.Bx == 1)`   ??  your object you shared,  doesnt appear to have any sort of name / id property

Comment: It's not the clickedBusinesses I need to filter, I need to filter the csv using clickedBusinesses

Answer (score 0):

```
const clickedBusinesses = [

];
const business = [
  { is_active: "1", Bx: "1", By: "1", Bz: "0", count: "5,133,151" },
  { is_active: "0", Bx: "1", By: "1", Bz: "0", count: "5,1121,151" },
  { is_active: "0", Bx: "1", By: "1", Bz: "0", count: "5,1212,151" },
]

// Update array and change button colour to reflect selection
function toggleClickedBuz(index, id) {
  var data = business[index];
  if (data) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
    clickedBusinesses.push(index);
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  for (let item of clickedBusinesses ) {
    console.log(item);
    // Do something
  }
}
```